# How to describe that the color of this pair of socks is too strong or colorful?

Tags: single-word-requests

I received this pair of socks (the blue one) from an online clothing recommendation service. But I want to return it because I think the color is too strong for me to handle or pair with other clothes. What is the most precise word that I can use to describe that this sock is too strong in its color and too challenging to pair with other clothes? I am not satisfied by just saying that the color is too strong/bright/colorful.

[image: two pairs of socks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Garish** or **gaudy** mean bright or showy in a tasteless way. If you're not actually trying to insult the socks, you could call them **flashy** or **loud.**

You could also say they **clash** with everything.

Comment: This has the potential to be a good answer if you [elaborate it and provide reference(s)](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the "good" words here :p I'm actually not disgusted by the sock, in fact, I think it looks beautiful by itself. It's just too flashy (thanks for that!) to be compatible with my style.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact lack of appeal you want to convey. If you wanted to suggest that they made you feel "sick" or "turned your stomach" you might say they had a "**bilious**"color combination (could be especially useful if they had the color yellow in them).

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bilious

Comment: Well, I'm not sick of the sock. I think for itself, it looks beautiful. I found it being too flashy (what I just learned :) and is just incompatible with my style. But thanks for the word "bilious"! I'm sure I will encounter it under other contexts.